# jQuery CDN | via JSAPI or direct CDN Load?

Tags: jquery, google-api, jsapi

What is better to load?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.7.2");
</script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: well the first has to make two request, whereas the second makes one

Answer (score 2):

well the first has to make two request, whereas the second makes one. It really depends what you are trying to do, the Google loader provides many options that can be useful:

From example:

```
function loadMaps() {
  google.load("maps", "2", {"callback" : mapsLoaded});
}
```

You can specify a callback, which can be awesome depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Also, check out autoloading which can reduce the amount of request you need to do for using Google API:

```
  <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=%7B%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22search%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22language%22%3A%22en%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22maps%22%2C%22version%22%3A%222.X%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22elements%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221.0%22%2C%22packages%22%3A%5B%22localsearch%22%5D%7D%5D%7D"></script>
```